# Is there a way to configure terraform to have a VM with an optional second nic?

Tags: terraform, vmware, network-interface

My current terraform setup a VMware vm with 2 nics.

I want to change it so the second nic (nfs) will be optional, and only if its parameters are stated in the tfvars file it will be created.

the parameters are

vsphere_vm_nfs_network
vsphere_vm_nfs_network_address
vsphere_vm_nfs_ip_address_start

this is the tf file.

```
variable "vsphere_vm_count"                {}
variable "vsphere_vm_name"                 {}
variable "vsphere_vm_num_cpus"             {}
variable "vsphere_vm_memory"               {}
variable "centos_root_password"                 {}
variable "vsphere_vm_resource_pool_id"     {}
variable "vsphere_vm_datastore_id"         {}
variable "vsphere_folder"                   {}
variable "vsphere_guest_id"                     {}
variable "vsphere_vm_network_id"           {}
variable "vsphere_nfs_vm_network_id"           {}
variable "vsphere_adapter_type"                 {}
variable "vsphere_disk_size"                    {}
variable "vsphere_template_uuid"                {}
variable "vsphere_domain"                   {}
variable "vsphere_vm_ipv4_gateway"         {}
variable "vsphere_vm_network_address"      {}
variable "vsphere_vm_ip_address_start"     {}
variable "vsphere_vm_nfs_network_address"  {}
variable "vsphere_vm_nfs_ip_address_start" {}
variable "vsphere_wait_for_guest_net_timeout"   {}
variable "vsphere_vm_firmware"             {}
variable "vsphere_dns_server_list"          {
    type    = list(string)
}


resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count                      = var.vsphere_vm_count
  name                       = "${var.vsphere_vm_name}${count.index + 1}"
  firmware                   = var.vsphere_vm_firmware
  resource_pool_id           = var.vsphere_vm_resource_pool_id
  datastore_id               = var.vsphere_vm_datastore_id
  folder                     = var.vsphere_folder
  num_cpus                   = var.vsphere_vm_num_cpus
  memory                     = var.vsphere_vm_memory
  guest_id                   = var.vsphere_guest_id
  wait_for_guest_net_timeout = var.vsphere_wait_for_guest_net_timeout

  network_interface {
    network_id      = var.vsphere_vm_network_id
    adapter_type    = var.vsphere_adapter_type
  }

    network_interface {
    network_id      = var.vsphere_nfs_vm_network_id
    adapter_type    = var.vsphere_adapter_type
  }

  disk {
    label           = "${var.vsphere_vm_name}${count.index + 1}"
    size            = var.vsphere_disk_size
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid    = var.vsphere_template_uuid

    customize {
      timeout        = 0
      
      linux_options {
        host_name    = "${var.vsphere_vm_name}${count.index + 1}"
        domain       = var.vsphere_domain
      }

      network_interface {
        ipv4_address = "${cidrhost(var.vsphere_vm_network_address, var.vsphere_vm_ip_address_start + count.index)}"
        ipv4_netmask = 24
      }

      network_interface {
        ipv4_address = "${cidrhost(var.vsphere_vm_nfs_network_address, var.vsphere_vm_nfs_ip_address_start + count.index)}"
        ipv4_netmask = 24
      }

      ipv4_gateway    = var.vsphere_vm_ipv4_gateway
      dns_server_list = var.vsphere_dns_server_list
    }
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "systemctl stop firewalld",
      "systemctl disable firewalld",
      "sed -i 's/net.ipv4.ip_forward=0/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf",
    ]
    connection {
      script_path     = "/script.sh"
      type            = "ssh"
      user            = "root"
      password        = var.centos_root_password
      host            = "${cidrhost(var.vsphere_vm_network_address, var.vsphere_vm_ip_address_start + count.index)}"
    }
  }

}

output "vsphere_vm_ip_addresses" {
 value = vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.*.clone.0.customize.0.network_interface.0.ipv4_address
}
```

and this is my tfvars

```
#  Configuration    
vsphere_vm_name                    = "vm-hard-1-20"
vsphere_vm_firmware                = "efi"    
vsphere_vm_count                   = "5"
vsphere_vm_num_cpus                = "48"
vsphere_vm_memory                  = "135168"
vsphere_vm_resource_pool           = "LAB-Cluster1/Resources/"
vsphere_vm_datastore               = "datastore_01"
vsphere_vm_ipv4_gateway            = "172.16.41.254"  
vsphere_vm_network                 = "-Support"
vsphere_vm_network_address         = "172.16.41.0/24" 
vsphere_vm_ip_address_start        = "201"
vsphere_vm_nfs_network             = "-NFS"
vsphere_vm_nfs_network_address     = "172.16.64.0/24" 
vsphere_vm_nfs_ip_address_start    = "201"
```

Thanks,
Aviram

Comment: Your TF code is invalid. You are using `count.index` yet your resource does not use `count`. Can you update the question with full and valid TF code? Also which parameters do you mean in "only if its parameters"?

Comment: updated, my issue is just with second nic for NFS

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [Dynamic Blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) to simplify this problem and so I would suggest changing the structure of your variables a little:

```
variable "vsphere_vm_nics" {
  type = list(map(string))
}
```

in your *.tfvars, you would then have a structure like:

```
vsphere_vm_nics = [
  {
    vsphere_vm_network = "1st NIC value"
    vsphere_vm_network_address = "1st NIC value"
    vsphere_vm_ip_address_start = "1st NIC value"
  },
  {
    vsphere_vm_network = "Optional 2nd NIC value"
    vsphere_vm_network_address = "Optional 2nd NIC value"
    vsphere_vm_ip_address_start = "Optional 2nd NIC value"
  }
]
```

Finally, modify the `network_interface` sections of your `vsphere_virtual_machine` resource to use dynamic blocks:

```
dynamic "network_interface" {
  for_each = toset(var.vsphere_vm_nics)
  content {
    ipv4_address = "${cidrhost(each.value["vsphere_vm_network_address"], each.value["vsphere_vm_ip_address_start"] + count.index)}"
    ipv4_netmask = 24
  }
}
```

In theory at least, this should allow to you specify as many NICs as you need, just by adding more or less to the list in `var.vsphere_vm_nics`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but took a different approach. It's maybe not the best approach but this post helped me so I wanted to share how I created dual NIC VMs with Terraform
**Note:** In my case I have a frontend that will set the value to `1` or `0` but I statically set it to `1` for testing

**variables.tf**

```
variable "dual_nic" {
  description = "Boolean for adding dual NIC to VM"
  default     = "1"
}
```

**instances.tf**

```
  network_interface {
    network_id     = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
    adapter_type   = var.adapter_type
    use_static_mac = true
    mac_address    = each.value["mac"]
  }
 
  network_interface {
    network_id     = var.dual_nic == 1 ? "${data.vsphere_network.network_two.id}" : "${data.vsphere_network.network_two.id}" 
    adapter_type   = var.dual_nic == 1 ? var.adapter_type : var.adapter_type
  }
```